# date timeline from start & end dates in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

In this sheet, I would like to have a date timeline generated from 6 inputs:

1- start date ( where timeline should starts )
2- end date ( where timeline should ends )
3- data presenting type (days, weeks or months)
4- weekend type to be excluded from timeline ( Friday & Saturday, Saturday & Sunday or No Days off)
5- weekend days that would be included in timeline ( due to overtime for example )
6- vacations should be excluded from timeline ( if same date is in vacation table & weekend days to include in timeline table, dates should be included in timeline.

I tried achieving this through "if" function, but I couldn't, it goes messy! I only succeed in generating days timeline as shown in the image! is it possible to achieve that without VBA? [image]

Comment: So you have 6 inputs. What are you trying to compute?

Comment: The output should be range of dates starting from input 1 (starting date) and ending to input 2 (ending date) considering the inputs of weekends, vacation, type of date (days, weeks, months)

Comment: My understanding is that depending on the filter options you want to have different dates generated. Please provide the Vacation and Weekend table sample in table markdown format. You can use the following [tool](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables#). For the option `No Day off` does it mean no date will be excluded from the Weekend table? Thanks

Comment: How would you present the output in the case of weeks or months? Do you want to show the start of the week/month? I guess your other filter option are not independent, they only make sense if you select as unit of scale: days, for weeks or months I don't think it make sense, you should build a dependent drop list, so when you select other value than days, such option won't be available.